# Одновременный ввод и дробных и отрицательных значений в edittext

Tags: java, android, xml

Если в ХМЛ разметке установить свойство `numberDecimal` для `edittext`-a, то в этот самый `edittext` нельзя будет вводить отрицательные значения. Если же установить свойство `numberSigned`, нельзя будет вводить дробные значения. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как этого избежать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте фильтры:

```
public class NegativeDecimalInputFilter implements InputFilter {
        private final Pattern mPattern;
        public NegativeDecimalInputFilter() {
            DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
            this.mPattern = Pattern.compile("(-)?(0|[1-9]+[0-9]*)?([\\"+dfs.getDecimalSeparator()+"][0-9]{0,2})?");
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

            String result =
                    dest.subSequence(0, dstart)
                            + source.toString()
                            + dest.subSequence(dend, dest.length());
            Matcher matcher = mPattern.matcher(result);
            if (!matcher.matches()) return dest.subSequence(dstart, dend);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Фильтр применяется к вводимому тексту, т.е. вы можете предотвратить ввод. В данном случае, если вводимый символ не удовлетворяет регулярке, он затирается. Актуально для copy-paste ввода или ввода в середину строки.

И дальше ваш EditText:

```
edt.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new NegativeDecimalInputFilter()});
```

ЗЫ Регулярку можете придумать по своему вкусу.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает. Правда при вводе данных вылазит полноценная qwerty клавиатура, а при использовании свойств nuberDecimal/Signed повторяется проблема вопроса, даже не смотря на фильтр. Возможно ли чтоб при вводе клавиатура содержала только цифры, знак "-" и "."?

Comment: @IgorGorokhov, попробуйте добавить         `edt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);` (или в разметке соответственно `number|phone`).

Comment: простите за глупый вопрос, но что такое "регулярка"?

Comment: Регулярное выражение. То, что передается в `Pattern.compile`.

Comment: Вы сделали все за меня, спасибо)

Comment: Добрый вечер) Возникала проблема с фильтром: при программном задании иррационального значения `edittext`-у происходит краш приложения. Есть идеи в чем таится проблема?

Comment: Максимальное количество символов после разделителя увеличил до 20 и проблема ушла)

Answer (score 2):

В подобной ситуации выкручивался так:
Возле EditText добавляю Button [image: введите сюда описание изображения] , обработчик берет значение из EditText и меняет знак. Затем записывает в EditText:

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText14);
double d = Double.parseDouble(et.getText().toString());
et.setText(String.format("%f",-d));
```

Comment: Спасибо) Сейчас использую такой же вариант, жаль что нет предусмотренного решения проблемы(

Answer (score 2):

Всё гораздо проще

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
```